# Download file and serve it (Spring WebClient -> Liferay Porlet.serveResource)

Tags: spring, liferay, portlet, spring-webflux, liferay-7

I want to implement a Liferay Portlet that downloads a **~1GB file** from a separate server, and serves it to the website visitor who clicked the link.

The file must be streamed in a **memory-efficient** way *(so no loading everything into memory)*, and the user should see the download **progress shortly after clicking** *(so no storing everything onto the local disk)*.

I must use [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) because it seems to be the standard for making web requests within Liferay 7 (RestTemplate will be [deprecated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)).

I started writing something like this, inspired by an example from the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#retrieve--):

```
Mono<DataBuffer> bodyMono = client.get()
 .uri("https://theotherserver.com/file94875.pdf")
 .retrieve()
 .bodyToMono(DataBuffer.class);
```

... which I would feed into the portlet's `MVCResourceCommand.serveResource()` via `PortletResponseUtil.sendFile`, which expects a `java.io.InputStream`.

Unfortunately WebClient gives me a `Mono<DataBuffer>` (or `Flux<DataBuffer>`), and another answer claims that [*reconstructing the InputStream defeats the purpose of using WebClient in the first place*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48055611/226958).

What would be the most efficient and WebClient-savvy way to implement this?

Comment: I might understand something wrong, but: Aren't you quite unaffected by Liferay's choices when writing a servlet?

Comment: bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class) is probably the better way, since it'll stream the set of DataBuffers out.
I had a related question once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426304/convert-writes-to-outputstream-into-a-fluxdatabuffer-usable-by-serverresponse  although I think this might be too complicated for your usecase - hence just here in comments, not in answer.

Comment: For those (like me) who aren't familiar with Liferay's programming model, can you elaborate on your constraints? Can you use a Spring MVC Controller or are you constrained to work with the Servlet response directly?

Comment: @OlafKock: Sorry my wording was very bad, I am not using any servlet, I am going via MVCResourceCommand. I edited my question.

Comment: @Frischling, Brian: Sorry I really should have said the servlet is powered via https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/portlet/bridges/mvc/MVCResourceCommand.html I edited my question to add more details. It is really a Liferay question.

Comment: Granted this is based on a `Flux<String>`, but does this provide any useful guidance? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51801335

Comment: Ah, right Liferay.  The documentation specifies, that you can .getPortletOutputStream(); after setting contentlengh (so browser knows how much to expect), you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426304/convert-writes-to-outputstream-into-a-fluxdatabuffer-usable-by-serverresponse

Comment: @Frischling: Feel free to post an answer, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case of Liferay, the documentation states, that you can use ....getPortletOutputStream() to retrieve an OutputStream.
After setting contentlengh (so browser knows how much to expect), you can use this: [Convert writes to OutputStream into a Flux<DataBuffer> usable by ServerResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426304/convert-writes-to-outputstream-into-a-fluxdatabuffer-usable-by-serverresponse)

To write your data to the OutputStream